# SQLDeveloper - Error on running statement but running script works fine?

Tags: sql, relational-database, oracle-sqldeveloper, entity-relationship

*In the SQLDeveloper software, there is a feature to run either a statement within a script or the entire script.*

My issue is that my SQL Script works fine when I run the entire script, but throws a `ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object` error when I try to run a single statement.

For example my script is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE "Movie" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE "Critic" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP TABLE "Review" CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE "Critic" (
  "cID" int NOT NULL, /* Since a review cannot have no critics*/
  "CriticName" varchar(100),
  "PhoneNumber" varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY ("cID")
);

CREATE TABLE "Movie" (
  "mID" int,
  "Title" varchar(255),
  "ReleaseDate" DATE,
  "Rating" int,
  "RunningTime" INTEGER, /*To store the duration of the film in minutes*/
  "Director" varchar(100),
  "Actor(s)" int,
  PRIMARY KEY ("mID")
);

CREATE TABLE "Review" (
  "rID" int,
  "mID" int,
  FOREIGN KEY ("mID") REFERENCES "Movie"("mID"),
  "cID" int,
  FOREIGN KEY ("cID") REFERENCES "Critic"("cID"),
  "Rating" int,
  PRIMARY KEY ("rID")
```

**Why would this script run fine as a whole but fail if I try to run just one statement?**

For reference, the feature I'm talking about looks like this in the GUI:

[image]

Comment: If you just run one statement you are probably missing the `drop` statements.

Comment: So because I have not dropped the tables yet, is the error being thrown since the tool is picking up older instance of tables from previous iterations of running the script?

Comment: Yes.  The error should be fairly obvious as well.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out due to @Gordon Linoff 's explanation.

The drop table command must be run before creating the table. And since the run statement command only runs a single statement, the drop command is never called, causing the error.

To fix this, one can simply highlight both the drop command and the create command and *then* click "Run Statement", resolving the issue.